# Error: attempt to apply non-function in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

I have successfully set up a Selenium session with R in a computer, but whenever I run any usual RSelenium functions - say, `remDr$open()`, I get the following message:

> Error: attempt to apply non-function

I find it extremely confusing, since I've used the same commands in another computer with no issues. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: There isn't much of an example, since I can't accomplish the most basic tasks. I write `remDr <- rsDriver(port = 4444L, browser = "chrome"` and successfully connect to the server, but R doesn't seem to recognize any of the inputs as functions. If I run `remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com.br/")`, I only get this cryptic error message.

Comment: @MaurícioSchwartsman Did you ever figure out why this was happening? Just ran into this issue on new laptop.

Comment: I did. I was using rsDriver() insted of remoteDriver().